# Why is きます used here? And what do でも and し mean?

Tags: nuances, particle-でも, particle-し

> 落語が好きです。特に古典落語が好きで同じお噺**でも**落語家によって感じ方が違います**し**、聴いた時の自分の環境や体調**でも違ってきます**。

To me, 違ってきます doesn't indicate a change, "become different more and more", but emphasises the writer's viewpoint. Here, how would it be different if the writer substituted 違います for 違ってきます? Can you make similar examples, please?

I still don't know if でも can be used like など, because they often have the same translation, "and so on", "or something", etc. To me, the first でも just means "even", but the second one can mean both "also" and "or something".

I don't understand if し shows a reason for what comes after or means "and".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

違ってきます means either 'gradually changes', or 'begins to change'. 違います would not imply gradualness of the change or suggest its beginning, just stating that something changes (state).

The second でも has the one of the meanings 'or the like, or something, maybe, say just', showing some form of modesty or diffidence, and one use of など corresponds to this. For example, 道が悪くてジープででも行かなければならない, 'The road is so bad, I'm afraid we will have to go by jeep', the 'I'm afraid' conveying diffidence. (Example from Martin.) So here, 'one's environment or bodily condition?/state? or the like gradually changes.'

し at the end of a sentence means 'and (also/moreover)', the difference from linking two sentences with -te, is that there need be no logical or temporal connection.